# SwiftUI How to implement dark mode toggle and refresh all views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, ios-darkmode

I'd like to implement a simple toggle to manually switch between dark and light modes. However, I don't know how to make my app refresh (redraw all windows) after I switch the toggle.

So far I found these answers [Manually set light/dark mode in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142948/manually-set-light-dark-mode-in-swiftui-and-save-users-choice) and [Implement dark mode switch in SwiftUI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476048/implement-dark-mode-switch-in-swiftui-app).

But both these solutions use `SceneDelegate.shared` which is not recommended according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547907/swift-ios13-access-scenedelegate-window-variable-in-a-viewcontroller).

```
var isDark: Bool = true {
    didSet { SceneDelegate.shared?.window!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = isDark ? .dark : .light }
}
```

Is there really no other option to implement this? I tried adding `@Environment` variable but it works only once when the application starts. And I need my app to update the color scheme on toggle change.

```
.environment(\.colorScheme, settings.isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
```

This is my toggle:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $settings.isDarkMode) {
            Text("Night mode")
        }
    }
}
```

In my model I have this variable:

```
@UserDefaultsBacked(key: UserDefaults.Keys.Settings.darkMode, defaultValue: false)
var isDarkMode: Bool
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476468

Comment: @SureshMopidevi This is the same answer I already linked in my question `Implement dark mode switch in SwiftUI App`. And it does not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.colorScheme` to your top View and add a color scheme variable (`@State`, `@Binding`, etc.). Whenever the variable changes the view (and children) update automatically.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var theColorScheme: ColorScheme = .dark

    func toggleColorScheme() {
        theColorScheme = (theColorScheme == .dark) ? .light : .dark
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack { // or any other View
            Color.primary // to make the change visible

            Button(action: self.toggleColorScheme) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }   .colorScheme(theColorScheme)
    }
}
```

**Note**: if you want to update the color scheme of the whole presentation, you're better of using `.preferredColorScheme` instead of `.colorScheme`.

Comment: This code does not work on Xcode 13.

Comment: @TomSchulz Just verified it still works with Xcode 13, but the example was very silly; the (original) VStack didn't contain any view that visibly changed with the colorScheme. I updates the example accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me

Step 1 :

```
struct AppName: App {

@AppStorage("appTheme") private var isDarkModeOn = false

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MainTabView()
            .preferredColorScheme(isDarkModeOn ? .dark : .light)
    }
}}
```

Step 2 :

Then you change this variable via button click

```
var body: some View {

@AppStorage("appTheme") private var isDarkModeOn = false

    VStack {
            Button {
                self.isDarkMode.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image("dark_mode_icon")
            }
      }}
```