# Swift macOS | Setting (switching between) dark and lightmode

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am working on a macOS app where I want to give users the ability to switch between light and dark mode.

For iOS apps, this can be done by simply overriding the `UserInterfaceStyle` of `UIWindow`. Like so:

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark //.light
```

The problem: `NSWindow` doesn't have a `UserInterfaceStyle` property.

I have tried to set the `NSAppearance`

```
window.appearance = NSAppearance(appearanceNamed: NSAppearance.Name.aqua, bundle: nil)
```

without success. It returns me an error saying: "RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find NSAppearanceNameAqua.car in bundle with identifier: ..."

I am stuck. Do you have any ideas?

[Here would be a solution for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476048/implement-dark-mode-switch-in-swiftui-app)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was on the right track!

```
window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
```

worked.

There is actually a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app) to set the appearance of macOS apps from apple.

Note: This also works if you have all your content inside a `NSPopover`, since it too has a property `appearance`.