# Implement toggle between System/Light/Dark Mode for SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, swiftui

Have been trying to add this functionality, but there is no live updating (I have to close and reload the app).

This tutorial ([SwiftUI: How to let the user set the app appearance in real-time w/ options "light", "dark", and "system"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798263/swiftui-how-to-let-the-user-set-the-app-appearance-in-real-time-w-options-lig)) has failed to work on iOS 15 and above :(

Comment: `preferredColorScheme` based approach should work

Comment: @Asperi it only works on the first change, afterwards I have to reload the app for the change to take place.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833313/10948558) still works for me.