# Using multicolor symbols on light/dark backgrounds in Strings

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm struggling to use sf-symbols with different background colours.
I've [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476048/implement-dark-mode-switch-in-swiftui-app) I can set a View to light or dark mode (e.g. to render a black symbol white when used on a dark background) but this does not appear to work when I embed the symbol in a string.

```
// Black background
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                Image(systemName: "suit.club.fill")
                Text("=> \(Image(systemName: "suit.spade.fill")) <=")
            }
            .symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50).background(.black)
     
 // White background
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                Image(systemName: "suit.club.fill")
                Text("=> \(Image(systemName: "suit.spade.fill")) <=")
 
            }
            .symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50).background(.white)
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in this screenshot the symbol (spades) in the Text view is not rendered according to the environment modifier even though the previous symbol (clubs) is.

One workaround is to display the Text as a concatonation of Strings and Images, but I'd rather avoid this so that I don't run into translation issues.
Any suggestions?

PS: This is primarily for use in visionOS which according to Apple does not have dark mode but renders text nevertheless in dark mode, whereas I want to have dark text on a light background.

Comment: If you simply want the suit symbols to have the same color as the text, use the Unicode characters ♥ ♦ ♠ ♣ in the text instead of trying to embed an image in the text. All four symbols will match the text color so no red for the heart or diamond.

Comment: No, I want them to render in multicolor, but intelligently, so that they don't disappear into the background. Apple handles this very well (see above - club with light&dark background), but NOT in the case of a symbol in a String.

Comment: Your issue is when you convert `Image` to text via string interpolation. The symbol is no longer a normal image. That's why the color is not changing in that case. My suggestion would likely work if you created an attributed string and applied the proper suit color to the symbol.

Comment: Yes, Image seems to be the problem. I'll have to use emoji's instead.

Comment: The color emojis will have the same issue as the images (I tried them before posting my original comment). They don't change color either. That's why I suggested the non-emoji symbols (which matches the text color but loses the red for the heart and diamond).

Comment: 1. Your updated solution doesn't work for the case where you want a black background (which is the whole point of your question). 2. Please don't update your question with the answer. Instead, post an actual answer below.

Comment: Apologies. I'll correct. In iOS it's not a problem because that supports dark and light mode so I don't need to have a white (or black) frame. The background is transparent and dark and light modes are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One way of inverting the color while using a `Text()` view can be by using the `.invertColor()` modifier ⬇️

`Text("\(Image(systemName: "suit.club.fill"))").colorInvert()`

This will show you your spade ♠️ SF Symbol in white (show below behind yours): ⬇️
[image: Spade SF Symbol shown in "white" color - end of the row]

But by reading your code I'll suggest you to continue using the `Image()` view just like you did for your other SF Symbols.

Comment: That would work if I could use: Text("\(Image(systemName: "suit.club.fill")).colorInvert())") I.e. include the modifier in the Text view. But I can't and neither can I "build" the text from single words since that would ruin the translatability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy with this solution, but it does sort of work in visionOS.

The workaround is to avoid the use of Images where possible and use emoji's instead. I'm disappointed but I don't see a way out of this if I want the string to be a translatable phrase, rather than concatenated bits and pieces. With iOS it's not a problem when the text is superimposed on the background. But in visionOS I want to have a solid background (not Glass).

So the solution looks like:

```
       VStack {
                Text("♣️ and ❤️ are best")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
       }
       .frame(width: 200, height: 50).background(.white)
```

[image: visionOS screenshot]